# ¿Cómo copiar objetos en Javascript excluyendo algunas propiedades?

Tags: javascript

Se que se pueden copiar objetos en `Javascript`, por ejemplo, utilizando [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const target = {};
const source = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
Object.assign(target, source);
console.log(target);
```

¿Cómo podía hacer si quisiera copiar en la variable `target` todas las propiedades de la variable `source` excepto, supongamos, `b: 2`?

Es decir, el resultado esperado sería `{"a": 1, "c": 3}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una forma bastante corta para un solo nivel es usando [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const source = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

const {b, ...res} = source;

console.log(res);
```

Además de `Object.keys` que propone the-breaker, que resulta bastante útil por darnos la posibilidad de usar las funciones de los arrays (como `.filter()`), existen otras formas que pueden resultar fundamentales en otros escenarios, por ejemplo si tenemos varios niveles y no conocemos la estructura del objeto, usando el callback de `JSON.parse` nos evita algunos dolores de cabeza:

```js
const source = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3,d:{b:4}};

const res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source), function (k, v) {
  if(k !== 'b') return v;     
});  

console.log(res);
```

Otra forma puede ser iterarando con `for..in` (un solo nivel):

```js
const source = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3,d:{b:4}};
const res = {};

for(let p in source){
  if(p !== 'b') res[p] = source[p];
}

console.log(res);
```

En todos los casos puede cambiar bastante si lo que tenemos es lo que queremos eliminar o lo que queremos dejar. En estos ejemplos asumo que no queremos "b", y los demás no importa.

Otra forma, bastante ilegible es combinando `Object.entries` con `Object.fromEntries` que nos permite usar por ejemplo el `.filter` como queramos, tanto el propiedades como en valores:

```js
let obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

const res  = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(e=>e[0]!=='b'));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: ¿se podía recorren un objeto con un `for`? y yo aquí usando un `forEach()`...

Comment: @Marcos el único posible problema en el ejemplo en realidad es únicamente con `Date`, ahora el `undefined` o `Infinity` se clonan bien. De cualquier manera no hay mucha opción para un deep clone nativo. Habría que tener en cuenta ese caso del date.

Comment: @Marcos de igual forma el Object.assign realiza una copia superficial, cuando son de dos o mas niveles copia  las referencias, lo ideal para este caso es usar lodash

Comment: @JackNavaRow, si eso ya lo se y no es a lo que apuntaba en esta pregunta, ni en las respuestas, solo quería señalarle a Emeeus el porque de un comentario que ya borre.

Answer (score 5):

Para resolverlo podrías recorrer el objeto `source` para asignar sus propiedades excluyendo `'b'` con `Object.keys()` y `forEach()` de la siguiente forma:

```js
const target = {};
const source = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

Object.keys(source).forEach(key => 
  key !='b' ? target[key]=source[key] : 0
);

console.log(target)
```

Aunque funciona si solo quieres omitir una propiedad, para omitir mas de una habría que agregar un *array* de las que se quieren omitir y buscar que no se incluyan esas propiedades, se podría hacer con `includes()`:

```js
const target = {};
const source = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5};

const omitir = ['b', 'e'];

Object.keys(source).forEach(key => 
  !omitir.includes(key) ? target[key]=source[key] : 0
);

console.log(target)
```

Espero que sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Que tal si agregamos algo a tu codigo, eliminando los elementos que no necesitas del objeto:

```js
const target = {};
const source = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
Object.assign(target, source);
console.log(target);
const borrarKeys = ["b"];

for (i= 0; i<= borrarKeys.length; i++){
  if (target.hasOwnProperty(borrarKeys[i])){
    delete target[borrarKeys[i]];
  } 


}
console.info(target);
```

---

Planteando otro punto de vista, que tal si creamos un Objeto de lo que necesitamos y luego lo copiamos:

```js
const target = {a : true, 
                b : true};
const source = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};


function copy(t,s){
  for (var prop in s) {
      if (t.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        t[prop] = s[prop];

      }
  }
}
copy(target,source)
console.log(target)
```